# How did A. Subaskaran come forward to produce 2.0?

Tags: 2.0

[A. Subaskaran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allirajah_Subaskaran) is the founder and chairman of Lycamobile, 
a **mobile virtual network operator**. The movie storyline is 
about how **mobile phones and mobile towers are harmful to birds**.

How did he come forward to produce 2.0?